# How to resolve java.nio.file.FileSystemException The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, selenium, file, selenium-webdriver, base64

I am getting the exception (java.nio.file.FileSystemException) while I run the this code

public String getScreenShotAsBase64() throws IOException {

```
File source = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Screenshots/image.png";
FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path));
byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(path));
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);
```

}

when I try to run the method it is not working throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is that Windows won't let your application open the "Screenshots/image.png" file for writing because something else already has it open.  It just won't.  See [File Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows) for an overview of Windows file locks and their purpose.

This SuperUser Q&A gives a number of ways to figure out which other application holds the file lock:

- [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902)

Your use of Selenium in this instance is (probably) not apropos.

---

You will most likely need to do one of the following to resolve this.

- Change your application to write the screenshot to another file if the first target file it chooses is locked.
- Tell the user that your application can't write the file.  The user message could suggest that they need to close whatever other application it is that has the image file open at the moment.
- If the other application is Windows itself (for some reason) you will probably need to rethink what you trying to do.

Comment: Hi Stephen Thanks for the response, its working now.

I just change the location for the screenshot path that it now it is working.
  String path = projectname/Base64/img.png";

Comment: I'm not sure why that solved your problem ... or if it is actually a good solution.  It depends on what was using the file with the other path and why.